# Can I set individual opacity levels for an ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've added a ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer and I've used the imageParameters.layerIds property to only show certain layers.

Is there a way to set a different opacity level for each layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general, you only get access to the symbology/opacity defined in the service itself.  that being said, dynamic layers capability added at 10.1 provides an opportunity to define an entirely new renderer on the clientside for ArcGISDynamicMapServices...

Here's a link to the ArcGIS Server help for configuring map services with dynamic layer support:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/About_dynamic_layers/0154000004zv000000/

Here's a sample from our JS API resource center for taking advantage of them:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/renderer_dynamic_layer_class_breaks.html

Comment: Thanks! Any idea on this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108381/why-isnt-my-arcgis-javascript-querytask-working

Comment: I'd be a lot more inclined to take a look if you wrote a jsbin or jsfiddle to repro the problem

Comment: I'll keep that in mind in the future. I scrapped it.